# HTML JSF inputText disable with checkbox

Tags: html, jsf, xhtml

```
<table class="layout-table"> 
<tr>
        <td><strong>a. Copy of Contract</strong>
            <br/>
            <p:inputText value="#{question4dDte}"></p:inputText>

             <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk1" value="#{question4dNA}"/> (something like this)
            <br/>
            <h:outputText id="counter24" />
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

So I have this code which is not working the way I want but I am not sure how to do it. I want to be able to have a inputText and a checkbox like this.

```
______________   ()
```

I was using the radio button because it is a circle but I would rather use a checkbox instead, (if its possible to make it a circle that would be awesome too :) ). But what I want to do is when the checkbox is clicked it disables the text field. When it is unchecked it enables the text field. But when the checkbox is selected it needs to put question4dNA to 2. This is where it makes it a bit harder :(.

Comment: Add `disabled` attribute in inputText and ajax `render` in checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
  <p:selectOneRadio id="radio" value="#{TheBean.theProperty}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="No p:inputText ;)" itemValue="NO" />
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="YES" itemValue="YEP" />
      <p:ajax update="txtHI" />
  </p:selectOneRadio>

  <p:inputText id="txtHI" disabled="#{TheBean.theProperty == 'NO'}" />
```

TheBean:

```
private String theProperty;
// set & get
```

I am using PrimeFaces but is almost the same. Try using f:ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a working example of this at http://prpdemo.com/disable-field.php. But here is the code to do what you need.

```
    <form name="form1" id="form1" action="#" method="post">
    <label for ="question4dDte">question4dDte
    <input type="question4dDte" name="question4dDte" id="question4dDte" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" onclick="disableField('question4dDte');">
    </form>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
    function disableField(fieldID)
      {
      // By passing a variable for the fieldID,
         you can use the same script for multiple fields and just pass the fieldID in the call.
      if($('#'+fieldID).is (':disabled'))
      {
        $('#'+fieldID).prop('disabled', false);
      }else{
        $('#'+fieldID).prop('disabled','disabled');
      }
      alert("The text box is disabled. "+$('#'+fieldID).is (':disabled'));
      // The previous line can be removed or commented out. It is just for confirmation that the form is working.
     }
    //-->
    </script>
```